# Copy multiple data with memcpy into char*

Tags: c++, struct, memcpy

I stuck at trying to copy the size of a struct the struct self and a word into one char array.

I know that memcpy isn't safe but it is the only way I know, if someone know a better way to do the same say it.

The crazy stuff is that the char array look like this:
04 01 00 00 STRUCTDATA 58 F9 57 00

The first 4 bytes should be: 260
And the last should be EOP\0

But it isn't.

The code looks like this:

```
const char * eop = std::string("EOP").c_str();
char pData[sizeof(int) + sizeof(_welcomeMessage) + sizeof(eop)];
int packetSize = sizeof(_welcomeMessage);
memcpy(pData, &packetSize, sizeof(packetSize));
memcpy(pData + sizeof(int), &_welcomeMessage, sizeof(_welcomeMessage));
memcpy(pData + sizeof(int) + sizeof(_welcomeMessage), &eop, sizeof(eop));
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: `sizeof(eop)` does not do what you think it does.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ([edit your question please](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25000977/edit)), that allows us to reproduce the behavior you notice. Also note as @dasblinkenlight pointed out, `sizeof(eop)` will yield the same value as `sizeof(const char*)`, and not the assigned literal's size.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you're right. I fixed it with using char[] = { 'E', 'O', 'P', '\0' }

Comment: Hm. I feel like there's a more C++ way to do this... it looks awfully like C.

Comment: You should change tag `c++` to `c`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first four bytes are indeed equal to 260.:)

`04 01 00 00`  in hex is equivalent to 4 + 256 that is equal to 260. So `04 01 00 00` is a correct internal representation of number 260.

As for the third part of the result then you are copying the address of pointer `eop` while as it seems you need to copy string literal "EOP".

I do not see any great sense in this definition

```
const char * eop = std::string("EOP").c_str();
```

Moreover using varaible eop leads to undefined behaviour because the temporary object of type std::string will be deleted at the end of the statement.

Why do not write simply as

```
const char * eop = "EOP";
```

or as

```
const char eop[] = "EOP";
```

in both cases you have to use identifier `eop` in the call of `memcpy` instead of expression `&eop` specifying the correct size of copied data.

As for the structire then it can be said nothing whether it was copied correctly because you did not show the structure definition and what you are going to obtain as the result of its copying.

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, after this statement:

```
const char * eop = std::string("EOP").c_str();
```

`eop` points to memory that is no longer valid, because the destructor for `std::string("EOP")` has run.